# Example of a primary representation that is not a multiple of an irreducible representation

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, von-neumann-algebras, irreducible-representation

Let $G$ be a group. A unitary representation of $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is called **primary** if for any invariant subspace $V\subseteq H$ one has that either:

1. $V\in \{0, H\}$.
2. There is a non-zero intertwining operator $T:V\to V^\perp$.

As an example: If $M$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, $\omega$ a cardinal then then $M^\omega$ is primary. In fact if $H$ contains a single irreducible representation $M$ and $H$ is primary then $H=M^\omega$ for some $\omega$.

Primary representations that are not a multiple of an irreducible are thus not allowed to contain any irreducible sub-representations, which motivates my **question**:

> Whats an example of a primary representation that is not a multiple of an irreducible representation?

It may be helpful to note that a representation is primary if and only if the von Neumann algebra generated by its image is a factor, ie has trivial center.

Comment: What is the Hilbert space structure on $M^{\omega}$ for $\omega$ infinite? Are you sure you don't mean the Hilbert space direct sum?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes, I mean the direct sum. Maybe $\ell^2(\omega)\otimes M$ is more exact notation, but also more unwieldy.

Comment: Some googling turned up https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63124/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-representation-and-a-irreducible-repres which says that the regular representation of the free group $F_2$ is an example.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand the answer correctly the statement is that the the regular representation of $F_2$ is not "type 1" (which I think means it does not decompose into irreducibles) and so admits primary subrepresentations that are not multiples of an irreducible.